# Milkmangames Easypush ANE, can an OS cancel click be detected

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, push-notification, actionscript, apple-push-notifications

I am calling

```
EasyPush.oneSignal.registerForNotifications();
```

At a relevant time in my program to initiate the iOS subscribe to push messages dialogue. If the user clicks OK I get a an event confirming acceptance and giving me the token.

However if the user clicks Cancel in the OS dialogue I do not get anything, if the user presses Cancel I wish to respond to this.

Can Cancel be detected?

I think this is the same issues as calling the register when Cancel has been previously pressed, because again nothing happens.

EDIT,

When a user clicks 'Agree' then the registered event occurs

```
PNOSEvent.TOKEN_REGISTERED
```

However, when 'Dont Agree' is clicked nothing happens, an event exists called

```
PNOSEvent.TOKEN_REGISTRATION_FAILED
```

However this never occurs and I do not know why, but if this event did occurs it would be what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you try **Event.ACTIVATE** from the **stage**? If your app loses focus to the system dialog then gains it back, **stage** should fire the ACTIVATE event.

Comment: @organis, thanks, but I think this is not the solution. I can use Event.ACTIVATE to detect once the os dialogue is closed, however that does not tell me what was clicked. When a user clicks Agree I get the PNOSEvent.TOKEN_REGISTERED callback, but nothing on cancel. Event.ACTIVATE occurs before PNOSEvent.TOKEN_REGISTERED event occurs, so I need to detect if I get back focus and the token registered event never occurs. The extension has an event PNEvent.TOKEN_REGISTRATION_FAILED however thats never called and I await the developers to respond.

Comment: Weeeel, you can set a timeout after ACTIVATE occurs and if there's no positive response within 1-2-5-10-whatever-you-see-suitable frames then process it as a negative case. I am well aware that it is a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: @organis, as always you are correct. your method is that advised by Milkman themselves.

Comment: Woohoo =^_^= . Well, good luck with your project then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from MilkmanGames themselves:

"Apple actually doesn't give us a notification for this case. What you could do is set a timeout (and/or listen for the next Event.ACTIVATE) and use the EasyPush.areNotificationsEnabled() function."